# Manipulate data on list with date period grouping by date/month

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, group-by, report

I have a list of Sales of services for specific time period (activationDate through endDate). I need to generate a sell report grouping by month-year (Eg April 2012). For each month I'd like to show how much full month of use and how many days.

My class:

```
 public class SaleMonth
 {
    public DateTime MonthYear { get; set; }//.ToString("Y")

    public int FullMonth { get; set; }
    public int DaysMonth { get; set; }

   public string TotalMonths { get { return String.Format("{0:N2}", 
                                  (((FullMonth * 30.5) + DaysMonth) / 30.5)); } }
 }
```

What I have tried:

```
using (CompanyContext db = new CompanyContext())
{
   var saleList =  db.MySales.ToList();
   DateTime from = saleList.Min(s => s.ActivationDate), 
       to = saleList.Max(s => s.EndDate);

   for (DateTime currDate = from.AddDays(-from.Day + 1)
                                .AddTicks(-from.TimeOfDay.Ticks); 
                 currDate < to; 
                 currDate = currDate.AddMonths(1))
   {
      var sm = new SaleMonth
      {
          MonthYear = currDate,
          FullMonth = 0,
          DaysMonth = 0
      };

      var monthSell = saleList.Where(p => p.ActivationDate < currDate.AddMonths(1) 
                                              || p.EndDate > currDate);
      foreach (var sale in monthSell)
      {
         if (sale.ActivationDate.Month == sale.EndDate.Month
             && sale.ActivationDate.Year == sale.EndDate.Year)
         {//eg 4/6/13 - 17/6/13
             sm.DaysMonth += (sale.EndDate.Day - sale.ActivationDate.Day + 1);
         }
         else
         {
            if (sale.ActivationDate.Year == currDate.Year 
                  && sale.ActivationDate.Month == currDate.Month)
               sm.DaysMonth += (currDate.AddMonths(1) - sale.ActivationDate).Days;
            else if (sale.EndDate.Year == currDate.Year 
                  && sale.EndDate.Month == currDate.Month)
               sm.DaysMonth += sale.EndDate.Day;
            else if(sale.ActivationDate.Date <= currDate 
                  && sale.EndDate > currDate.AddMonths(1))
               sm.FullMonth++;
          }                               
       }
       vm.SaleMonthList.Add(sm);
   }
}
```

I have a feeling that I'm missing something here and there must be a more elegant way to do it.

[Here is a picture](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxWpAttQo5u7dGRZS2g4eUYwTU0/edit?usp=sharing) showing some sells and the report generated from them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ does contain a way to group your data. Start by taking a look at this statement:

```
// group by Year-Month
var rows = from s in saleList
    orderby s.MonthYear
    group s by new { Year = s.MonthYear.Year, Month = s.MonthYear.Month };
```

The above statement will take your data and group it by Year-Month so that it will create a main key for each Year-Month combination and create a group of all corresponding `SaleMonth` items into that group.

When you grasp that, the next step is to use those groups to calculate whatever you want to calculate within each group.  So, if you were just looking to total all the `FullMonths` and `DaysMonths` for each Year-Month, you could do this:

```
var rowsTotals = from s in saleList
    orderby s.MonthYear
    group s by new { Year = s.MonthYear.Year, Month = s.MonthYear.Month } into grp
    select new
    {
        YearMonth = grp.Key.Year + " " + grp.Key.Month,
        FullMonthTotal = grp.Sum (x => x.FullMonth),
        DaysMonthTotal = grp.Sum (x => x.DaysMonth)
    };
```

**Edit:**

After looking again at what you're doing, I think it would be more efficient to do this:

```
// populate our class with the time period we are interested in
var startDate = saleList.Min (x => x.ActivationDate);
var endDate = saleList.Max (x => x.EndDate);

List<SaleMonth> salesReport = new List<SaleMonth>();
for(var i = new DateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, 1); 
    i <= new DateTime(endDate.Year, endDate.Month, 1);
    i = i.AddMonths(1))
{
    salesReport.Add(new SaleMonth { MonthYear = i });
}

// loop through each Month-Year
foreach(var sr in salesReport)
{
    // get all the sales that happen in this month
    var lastDayThisMonth = sr.MonthYear.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
    var sales = from s in saleList
        where lastDayThisMonth >= s.ActivationDate, 
        where sr.MonthYear <= s.EndDate
    select s;

    // calculate the number of days the sale spans for just this month
    var nextMonth = sr.MonthYear.AddMonths(1);
    var firstOfNextMonth = sr.MonthYear.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1).Day;
    sr.DaysMonth = sales.Sum (x =>
        (x.EndDate < nextMonth ? x.EndDate.Day : firstOfNextMonth) -
            (sr.MonthYear > x.ActivationDate ? 
             sr.MonthYear.Day : x.ActivationDate.Day));

    // how many sales occur over the entire month
    sr.FullMonth = sales.Where (x => x.ActivationDate <= sr.MonthYear && 
                                nextMonth < x.EndDate).Count ();
}
```

Comment: Really thank you! I like the way of filling dates and then go through them and take data accordingly.
In addition to retrieving all sales by the date given is very helpful for me somewhere else - on clicking the "details" for each row in the report.
So +1 twice =)

Comment: Hi Ijust get this error on the Sum func.. "only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in linq to entities" i try to change the addMonth(1) to a external var - monthLetter but stil get this exception' do you have eny idle?

Comment: @oCcSking, yes, for Linq-to-Entities, you must remove all your parameterless constructors that are being created. If you take a look at my edit, I've changed all the queries that should get you going again and at least will get you running to make tweaks.

Comment: 10Q!! that work =) but to fit the function like i was showing on the picture i had to chang the sum function to this one => sales.Sum(x =>
                            (x.EndDate < nextMonth ? x.EndDate.Day+1 : firstOfNextMonth) -
                                (sr.MonthYear > x.ActivationDate ?
                                (x.EndDate < nextMonth ? sr.MonthYear.Day : firstOfNextMonth)
                                 : x.ActivationDate.Day)); 10x again

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mr. Rem that LINQ is the way to go.  Since your calculations are complicated, I would create a helper function as well:

```
Func<DateTime, DateTime, bool> matchMonth = (date1, date2) => 
   date1.Month == date2.Month && date1.Year == date2.Year;
```

You can then create a function to use in your calculations:

```
Func<MySale, DateTime, int> calcDaysMonth = (sale, currDate) => 
{
     if (matchMonth(sale.ActivationDate, sale.EndDate))
     {
             return (sale.EndDate.Day - sale.ActivationDate.Day + 1);
     }
     else
     {
        if (matchMonth(sale.ActivationDate, currDate))
           return (currDate.AddMonths(1) - sale.ActivationDate).Days;
        else if (matchMonth(sale.EndDate, currDate)
           return sale.EndDate.Day;
        else 
           return 0;
     }
}
```

If you combine these techniques with Mr. Rem's, you should have a nice, readable, concise function that gathers your data for you and is easy to test and debug.

Comment: This is true, and much more elegant in terms of reuse.. the truth I was looking for more change in performance in terms of time and space
complexity or change the methode like linq or someother lovely stuff :) 10x anyway..